# Which window manager or desktop environment is in this image?

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, i3

Which distribution is the one in the picture below. More precisely, in which distribution can I find that top bar with the navigation numbers on the left ?

[image: Which one ?]

Comment: The picture is *quite* old btw.

Comment: the bar itself is i3bar and the navigation numbers belong to workspace switcher

Comment: Nowadays there is an interesting i3 compatible Wayland compositor: https://github.com/swaywm/sway

Comment: Also, if you look at the image closely, there are some URLs for [i3wm.org](http://i3wm.org)
 and its subdomains

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Some random distro that happens to be running i3 window manager.

https://i3wm.org/

Per [i3wm site](https://i3wm.org/downloads/) the window manager is distributed in Debian, Arch, Gentoo, Ubuntu, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, OpenSUSE, Megeia, Fedora, Exherbo, PiBang and Slackware.

Answer (score 34):

The screenshot is definitively the i3 window manager, and most probably is Arch Linux.

If you look well, the screenshot is from 2012, and there is an IRC session there, in the IRC channel #i3, and a browser with several pages open at the site https://i3wm.org

It is easier googling after the IRC nick `thevdvde` later also known as `thevdude`, than try to guess things. It is easy to find him in twitter, reddit and github, and to correlate the old user handle to the new handle.

The user behind that nick does indeed uses Linux, has a github  with Linux specific packages, and talks about using Arch Linux in the time period of that picture (the picture has a date of 2012).

> thevdude 24 Sept 2014
>   I know you're just teasing, but I've got a machine with an arch
>   install from over two years ago that's still running great. Just did
>   an -Syyu to get bash updated.

So we can be pretty much sure it is indeed Linux, and there is a big probability of it being indeed Arch Linux.

Comment: The IRC channel in the screenshot is also #i3.

Comment: This is both impressive and creepy.